# Refer (inline) to table produced by parameters::model_parameters() and print_md()?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to format results from a *t*-test conducted in R using RMarkdown. I want to format the results in a table. `parameters::print_md()` does so nicely, but I need to refer to the table using an inline reference, such as `\@ref(tab:ttest)`. I believe I need to use `bookdown::pdf_document2` to do so. I am using R 4.3.1 under macOS Ventura 13.4.1 through RStudio Version 2023.06.0+421, and compiling to PDF with `tinytex_0.46`.

When I try to do so, the reference is not recognized. See the minimal example of a `.Rmd` file below.

````
---
title: "Test {parameters}"
author: "Emily Dickinson"
date: "2023-08-18"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

I need to refer to Table \@ref(tab:ttest).

```{r ttest}
library(parameters)
data(mtcars)

# Conduct t-test:
t_out <- t.test(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars)

# Extract parameters and print for Markdown:
parameters::model_parameters(t_out) |> parameters::print_md()
```

I still need to refer to Table \@ref(tab:ttest).
````

The output appears as

[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{bookdown}'s cross-referencing abilities rely on some [neat behind-the-scenes features](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html) from `knitr::kable()` to work. It automatically inserts reference labels to the table environment (HTML or LaTeX or Word):

> The `kable()` function will automatically generate a label for a table environment, which is the prefix `tab:` plus the chunk label. For example, the table label for a code chunk with the label `foo` will be `tab:foo`, and we can still use the syntax `\@ref(label)` to reference the table.

`parameters::print_md()` doesn't do the same label injection that `kable()` does, so it doesn't work right away.

However, [the end of the documentation page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html) shows how to insert your own cross-referencable label and caption you can insert your own label into the table caption:

> To be able to cross-reference a Markdown table, it must have a labeled caption of the form `Table: (\#label) Caption here`, where `label` must have the prefix `tab:`, e.g., `tab:simple-table`.

You can do this with `parameters::print_md()`:

```
parameters::model_parameters(t_out) |> 
  parameters::print_md(caption = "Table: (\\#tab:ttest) Caption here")
```

…so your full document would look like this:

````
I need to refer to Table \@ref(tab:ttest).

```{r whatever-chunk-name-you-want}
library(parameters)
data(mtcars)

# Conduct t-test:
t_out <- t.test(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars)

# Extract parameters and print for Markdown:
parameters::model_parameters(t_out) |> 
  parameters::print_md(caption = "Table: (\\#tab:ttest) Caption here")
```
````

---

As an alternative, you can use Quarto, which doesn't require custom manual labels and works with any table-generating functions:

````
I need to refer to @tbl-ttest.

```{r tbl-ttest}
#| tbl-cap: A t-test.
library(parameters)
data(mtcars)

# Conduct t-test:
t_out <- t.test(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars)

# Extract parameters and print for Markdown:
parameters::model_parameters(t_out) |> parameters::print_md()
```
````

Comment: This looks great, @Andrew. One note: Your exact `print_md()` code works, but outputs `Table 1: Table: Caption here`. When I amend it to

```
parameters::model_parameters(t_out) |> 
  parameters::print_md(caption = "(\\#tab:ttest) Caption here")
```

the caption label looks appropriate. I'll try Quarto next. Thanks!

Comment: The Quarto version works well, with greatly simplified section, figure, and table reference, as you suggested. (My only Quarto quibble is the different the section and title font versus the main text font.) Thanks again!